# is there any keyword 'capital' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling a function named 'capital()' but it is not working and 'capita' is working.
is it a keyword in js or what is this ?

here is the code see it, test it

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HTML Select Element</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function capita(){
alert('yes');
c = new Array("Islamabad", "Tehran", "Bejing", "New Delhi", "Kabul");

var i;
i = document.f1.country.selectedIndex;
document.f1.capital.value=c[i];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Countries and Capital</h3>
<form name="f1" method="post">
The capital of 
<select name="country" id="country" onChange="capita();">
<option selected>Pakistan
<option>Iran
<option>China
<option>India
<option>Afghanistan 
</select>
is <input type="text" name="capital" value="Islamabad"/> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the function is being called on select list's event onchange

Comment: **Please show us your code**.

Comment: @Bilal: You can **edit** your question to improve it. Posting code into comments is not useful.

Comment: i have tested using alert('success'); on top of my function it is not triggring bt with function name capita all is well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`capital` is a reference to your input element.

```
<input type="text" name="capital" value="Islamabad"/>
```

This is because when you use inline handlers, there are certain DOM elements that are inserted into the variable scope chain. Exactly which elements are inserted depends on the browser to some degree.

If you change the `onchange` handler of your `select` element to this:

```
<select name="country" id="country" onChange="alert(capital);">
```

You'll see that it alerts:

```
"[object HTMLInputElement]"
```

...or something similar.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FW8SM/)**

---

Here's an updated example that changes your inline handler like this:

```
<select name="country" id="country" onChange="alert('LOCAL: ' + capital + 
                                             '\n\nGLOBAL: ' + window.capital);">
```

So now it alerts `capital` and `window.capital`. If you test this in different browsers, you'll probably get different results.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FW8SM/2/)**

Chrome shows:

> LOCAL: [object HTMLInputElement]
>
> GLOBAL: function capital() {}

Answer (score 4):

No, `capital` is not a [JavaScript keyword](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1). It's not on either the current keyword list or the list of future reserved words. (Not even the longer former list from the previous spec.)

The problem with your code is that in some browsers, all `name` values end up being globals. And of course, so do all functions declared at global scope. So you have a conflict (on those browsers) between your function `capital` and the element with the `name` "capital" in your markup. Changing either of them resolves the problem. Internet Explorer, in particular, has this issue.

In general, avoid adding any code symbols to global scope at all (unless you're writing a library, in which case a *single* symbol named as uniquely as reasonable is acceptable). For instance, there's no need for your code to have any global code symbols at all:

HTML:

```
<form name="f1" method="post">
The capital of 
<select name="country" id="country">
  <option selected>Pakistan</option>
  <option>Iran</option>
  <option>China</option>
  <option>India</option>
  <option>Afghanistan</option>
</select>
is <input type="text" name="capital" value="Islamabad"> 
</form>
```

JavaScript (only with changes related to global symbols; there are several other things I'd recommend changing as well):

```
// Everything within a scoping function
(function() {

  // The capitals
  var capitals = [
    "Islamabad",
    "Tehran",
    "Bejing",
    "New Delhi",
    "Kabul"
  ];

  // Hook the window#load event
  hookEvent(window, "load", handleLoad);

  // Handle the load event
  function handleLoad() {

    // Hook the "change" event on "country"
    hookEvent(
      document.getElementById("country"),
      "change",
      countryChanged
    );
  }

  // Handle a change of the country
  function countryChanged(event) {
    document.f1.capital.value = capitals[document.f1.country.selectedIndex];
  }

  // === Utility functions, don't need if you have a decent library

  function hookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
    // Very quick-and-dirty, recommend using a proper library,
    // this is just for the purposes of the example.
    if (typeof element.addEventListener !== "undefined") {
      element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    }
    else if (typeof element.attachEvent !== "undefined") {
      element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
    }
    else {
      element["on" + eventName] = handler;
    }
  }
})();
```

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/oziwux)